# How to populate a dynamic dropdown list based on a value and a table

Tags: microsoft-excel, data-validation

I have a table as follows:

```
Item Name       Slot        
Bronze Dagger   Main Hand   
Shortbow        Off Hand    
Magic Staff     Main Hand
```

and so on.

I want to have a drop down list somewhere using data validation, which filters this table but uses the item names. So it will show all the item names, but only the item names where the slot is set to "Main Hand", for example. I can't work out how to do this.

Thanks!

Comment: have a look [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal02.html) or [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dependent-drop-down-lists.html)

Comment: Neither of those links explain what I am looking for. This table I have will grow, and I will only have 1 table. I need to do something like have a Vlookup returning all matching answers etc. They will not be ordered in the table. I could have a bunch of items as main hand, then off hand, then some more main hand etc. I need to pull out the item names from the table where the slot matches Main hand, without ordering that table. Using indirect and ranges is no use, as the data isn't all together in the table.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you'd know what to do if you could reference your selection, I did a simple drop-down list on your Items.

Insert DropDown List from your menu. Set up the range of cells to refer to (your items), then link it to a local cell to offer a value. When a '1' is returned, that's the first item in the 'sorted list' (Excel assumes it's alphabetized also).

A2:A4 (A2 through A4) refers to your item's list. E2 is my preference to hold the value of the item selected in my list as you can see below in the image.

Hope this helps! Follow up with me if this helped out and/or if you get stuck.

[image]